# Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$, show that $(U^{0})_0 = U$

Tags: linear-algebra

It is pretty obvious why $(U^{0})_0 \supseteq  U$.

but how do I show that $(U^{0})_0 \subseteq   U$?

For clarification: $U^{0} = \left \{ \phi\in V^{*} \mid \phi(a) = 0, for \; u \in U\right \}$

$(U^{0})_0 = \left \{ u\in V \mid \phi(u) = 0, for \; \phi \in U^{0}\right \}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Sorry, I changed it to $u \in V$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Given $v\notin U$, show there exists $\phi\colon V\to k$ with $\phi(v)=1$ and $\phi|_U=0$.